# Google Places API returning an error when the device is moved to a different location

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I recently started working with Google Maps API and right now I am working on an application that is using **Google Places API**.

So to use the Google Places API, I am getting the server key i.e. the Public Access Key.

Now, while creating the API Key, it asked me to specify the IP Address of the device or the machine I am using in.

Places API does require this key in order to get the information you need.

Everything works great on my device when I am at one location.

**My Issues here are :**

**1)** When a user installs this application, how will the application work since it's using my IP Address to generate the Server Key.

**2)** When I installed my app in my device, it worked perfect when I was one location. Now, does my Device IP changes every time when I switch my location? If Yes, how can the application work if the IP is changing because only IP Addresses are specified for the Places API Key.

**3)** How will the users use this application if every device will have a different IP Address?

**This is the URL I am using to get the nearby places and it works for me at one specific location.**

```
**URL :** https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=some_latitude,some_longitude&radius=5000&types=food&sensor=true&key=THE_SERVER_KEY
```

Any suggestion on this issue will really help a lot. Thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 0):

I read the **documentation** and I saw that you had to put the **IP Address** only when you **restrict others to use your Server Key**.

I basically removed the IP Addresses from the API Console and now it's working good.

So, if you are testing the app with the server key for your testing purposes, then only put the **IP Address** for require the Server Key.

Comment: Solved the answer by reading the documentation. It's working fine now.